# Add image options programmatically in custom attribute not working

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, catalog

I want to add new custom option to upload image like extension : https://shop.emiprotechnologies.com/documentation/custom-option-image-for-magento-2 . 
So basically , i override some file to add new custom and function to upload, but image not save in pub/media and save name file on database

1. Create module :  
2. Declare your new product option :  **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/product_options.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_options.xsd">
    <option name="select" label="Select" renderer="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Type\Select">
        <inputType name="gallery" label="Thumb Gallery" />
        <inputType name="gallery_popup" label="Thumb Gallery Popup" />
        <inputType name="gallery_multi_select" label="Thumb Gallery Multi Select" />
        </option>

</config>
```

3. Override file **Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions to add new custom option :** 
*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml :*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" type="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" />
</config>
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php*

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use [...];

class CustomOptions  extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier
{
    const FIELD_IMAGE = 'image';
    const FIELD_COLOR = 'color';
    [...]
    protected function getSelectTypeGridConfig($sortOrder)
{
    $options = [...];

    return [],
        'children' => [
            'record' => [
                'arguments' => [...],
                'children' => [
                    static::FIELD_TITLE_NAME => $this->getTitleFieldConfig(
                        10,
                        $this->locator->getProduct()->getStoreId() ? $options : []
                    ),
                    static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME => $this->getPriceFieldConfigForSelectType(20),
                    static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME => $this->getPriceTypeFieldConfig(30, ['fit' => true]),
                    static::FIELD_SKU_NAME => $this->getSkuFieldConfig(40),
                    static::FIELD_IMAGE => $this->getImageFieldConfig(50),
                    static::FIELD_COLOR => $this->getColorFieldConfig(70),
                    static::FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME => $this->getPositionFieldConfig(92),
                    static::FIELD_IS_DELETE => $this->getIsDeleteFieldConfig(95)
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
   protected function getImageFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
          'arguments' => [
              'data' => [
                 'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Upload'),
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'formElement' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Media\Image::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_IMAGE,
                    'dataType' => \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Media\Image::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
 }
    [...]
}
```

Now, you can select image to upload, but image not save file name on database. what is mistake in my code.. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Wightman, did you find the solution for your question because I too need the same implementation.

If you got an answer, kindly post it here. Otherwise would someone help for this?